# USB Type C as TCP/IP?

Tags: android, windows, usb

Let's say I connect my Android phone to Windows PC using USB Type C. Is it **possible** to access TCP/IP services in the PC from my Android phone ? For example, connect to SQL Database in my Windows PC.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Why the downvote? I know this is obviously not the normal way. Therefore, I am asking for possibility.